# Scraping a site using GuzzleHttp User-Agent variable passing in header working on local server but not linux server?

Tags: php, yii2, guzzle6, guzzle

**Here is my code to scrape site using GuzzleHttp**

```
    $proxySetting=[
            'proxy' => $proxyServer,
            'headers' => [
                'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
                 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36',
            ]
        ];
    $response = $client->request(
        'GET',
        $url,
        $proxySetting
    );
```

When I pass the header with user-agent in my local machine using WAMP server it get the data from partner site, but when I hit the request without user-agent variable form local machine it return `403 forbidden error`. The same error is return form my Linux with the user-agent variable. So my question is why the user-agent variable is not working on server.

Comment: On live, it could be HTTPS certificate that you would require to pass in.

Comment: What is in `$proxyServer`?

Comment: @vivek_23 server url contain http not https.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used socks proxy but this site doesnt need any proxy so null in this case for both server live and local. which is working locally without any proxy

Comment: Are you sure that this is problem with `user-agent`? This site could just block IP of your server - if it checks user agent, it means that it does not want to be scrapped and may have other countermeasures than user agent check.

Comment: @rob006 This issue is only on my server tested it on other servers and my localserver it works fine in everywhere.

Comment: So I would guess that IP of your server is blocked and you can't do much about this. You may try to use some proxy to confirm that using different IP o the same server works fine.

Comment: @rob006 I am using sock proxy server throwing 403 forbidden error. may be https proctol but i am sending false all of this                             CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1,
                            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true